# devspace behind coporate proxy

Tags: proxy, devspace

I am installing [devspace](https://devspace.cloud/) in my local windows machine using npm

```
npm install -g devspace
```

after installed, it needs to Finish installation of DevSpace CLI, in which the following request is failed

```
Error requesting URL: https://github.com/devspace-cloud/devspace/releases/download/v5.1.0/devspace-windows-amd64.exe
```

I think it's because of my machine is using the company's proxy. However, I don't know how to config proxy in devspace (just like git, for example).

Answer (score 2):

DevSpace maintainer here. Instead of using npm, you can also download the release binary manually from GitHub: https://github.com/devspace-cloud/devspace/releases/

You can just do this:

1. Download the `devspace-windows-amd64.exe` for a release
2. Rename the downloaded file to `devspace.exe`
3. Save the `devspace.exe` file in a folder (and add this folder to your PATH environment variable) => You may need to restart after changing the PATH variable

That's basically what the npm installer does as well but it seems like it is unable to download the binary from GitHub. This may be because of a proxy or because of anything related to GitHub (your company may hit the rate limit or something else).